# Count records with a specified condition from from a list of tables in SQLServer(T-SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I'm trying to achieve something similar to this example PostgreSQL code but on SQLServer(T-SQL). I will attach the PGSQL code below.

The output I'm expecting is i have a list of table names in another table. `SELECT table_name FROM dbo.table_list`. This list could also come from the information schema.

Then i would like to `count(*)` the records in this table with the same where clause every time `WHERE status = 'CURRENT'` this field is present on each table in this list.

Here is an example of the PostgreSQL code:

```
SELECT
table_schema, 
table_name, 
(xpath('/row/cnt/text()' , xml_count))[1]::TEXT::INT AS row_count

FROM (
SELECT 
table_name, 
table_schema, 
query_to_xml(format('SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN status = ''CURRENT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
             FROM %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') AS xml_count
FROM  information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema =    'my_schema'
  AND table_name   LIKE 'new_%'
) my_fancy_table
```

This is the output I'm getting:

> table_schema     table_name      row_count
>
> -------------------    ---------------      --------------
>
> my_schema         new_tt1                1265
>
> my_schema         new_tt2                2111
>
> my_schema         new_tt3                564589
>
> my_schema         new_tt4                9999
>
> my_schema         new_tt5                0

Ideally i would need this in a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.count_currs()
  RETURNS TABLE(a character varying, b character varying, c integer) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  RETURN QUERY (SELECT table_schema::VARCHAR, table_name::VARCHAR, (xpath('/row/cnt/text()', xml_count))[1]::text::int FROM ( SELECT table_name, table_schema, query_to_xml(format('select SUM(CASE WHEN status = ''CURRENT'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as cnt from %I.%I', table_schema, table_name), false, true, '') as xml_count from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'my_schema' and table_name LIKE 'new_') t) ;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION public.count_currs()
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

So in my code i would have:

```
SELECT * FROM public.count_currs();
```

Please excuse my verbose explanation. I appreciate all the assistance!

-- EDIT

As has been requested you can use this to create some sample data and I'll attached the expected outcome. Please note that the number of tables and the table names are not set and could be 1 table could be 1000 tables i need this to be built dynamically based off the information schema (see code above) or from another table (see code above). The idea is that for each table in this list of tables returned we execute a query that will do something like this `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_schema.table_name WHERE status = 'CURRENT'` then group the counts from the x number of tables into a single result set :

Code to create sample data:

```
CREATE SCHEMA [my_schema];

CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[tt1](
    [status] [varchar](100) NULL);

CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[tt2](
    [status] [varchar](100) NULL);

CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[tt3](
    [status] [varchar](100) NULL);

CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[tt4](
    [status] [varchar](100) NULL);

CREATE TABLE [my_schema].[tt5](
    [status] [varchar](100) NULL);


INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt1] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');


INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt2] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt2] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');

INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt3] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');


INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt4] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt4] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt4] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt4] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt4] VALUES ('CURRENT');

INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt5] VALUES ('CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt5] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt5] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt5] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
INSERT INTO [my_schema].[tt5] VALUES ('NOT_CURRENT');
```

Then i would expect this a result:
[Example of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wafyA.png)

Comment: Your explanation is not bad @Nash, however, please provide us with some sample data to better understand your expected results...?

Comment: Hi @Birel. My goal is a dynamic query that can count the number of records with a status of  'CURRENT' for a dynamic list of tables. If this were possible for eg: `SELECT count(*) FROM @table_name WHERE status = 'CURRENT';` But @table_name is a single table at a time from a list of tables. Then these results are displayed in a single result set. The data in each table is wildly different but each will have a status field in it. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Please provide DDL+DML: queries to create the relevant table(s) and insert sample data

Comment: @RonenAriely Sample data has been added with a simpler explanation of what i need as an output.

Comment: SQL server has no way of `EXEC-ing` a dynamic SQL Statement as part of a query (except in a CLR function). You would need to create a CLR function for this (possibly specific to the task or just emulating `query_to_xml`) or generate the entire dynamic SQL statement accessing all of the tables up front - or just execute separate queries

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Are CLR functions an option? (they are not available in Azure SQL database)

Comment: I'm unsure what CLR is actually. Sorry i'm fairly new to SqlServer. But ill give this a try. i'm not running on Azure DB that i'm sure. I'm using SQL Server 2015 and 2017 (if this can be done on both). But i would appreciate an example i can try.

Comment: CLR gives you the ability to execute modules written in .NET languages. They are less restrictive than native SQL functions. In that it will allow you to execute dynamic SQL queries

Comment: The requirement i'm given is that at the end of the day i can execute something like this `SELECT * FROM [my_schema].get_counts();` and that will return the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server has no analog of `query_to_xml` and no way of `EXEC`-ing a dynamic SQL Statement built up as part of the same query except in a CLR function.

The CLR function below does what you need (TODO: add error handling) but you might also consider generating the entire dynamic SQL statement accessing all of the tables up front - or just execute separate queries to get the same result.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{

    [SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read)]
    public static SqlInt32 CountRowsWithCurrentStatus(SqlString schemaName, SqlString tableName)
    {
        string quotedSchemaName = string.Format("[{0}]", schemaName.Value.Replace("]", "]]"));
        string quotedTableName = string.Format("[{0}]", tableName.Value.Replace("]", "]]"));

        string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + quotedSchemaName + "." + quotedTableName + " WHERE status = 'CURRENT'";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {
                return new SqlInt32((int)cmd.ExecuteScalar());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

with that in place the query is

```
SELECT table_name,
       table_schema,
       [dbo].[CountRowsWithCurrentStatus](table_schema, table_name)
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  table_schema = 'my_schema'
       AND table_name LIKE 'tt_%'
```

Comment: I will try this shortly much apprecited!

Comment: @Nash - If you have never deployed one before then the easiest way is to add it to a SQL Server Data Tools project and publish from that. You might need to use `sp_configure` to change options for 'clr strict security' AND  'clr enabled'  if not already enabled

Answer (score 0):

Good day,

Assuming I understand your need and we can avoid using function, then this is a simple case of dynamic query. To confirm it please check if the following query fits your need. Use Stored Procedure to execute the code instead of function (again, assuming this fit your needs).

As you said, you have a table with the list of the tables (or we can use the system tables in order to get the list of tables), so first I will create it - this is not part of the solution:

```
CREATE TABLE table_list (S_Name sysname, T_Name sysname)
GO
INSERT table_list (S_Name, T_Name) values 
('my_schema','tt1'),
('my_schema','tt2'),
('my_schema','tt3'),
('my_schema','tt4'),
('my_schema','tt5')
GO
```

And now we can solve your needs with simple dynamic query

```
----------------------------- Solution
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX)
;With MyCTE AS (
SELECT 
    MyQueryOnSingleTable = 'SELECT ''' + S_Name + ''' as [Schema_name], ''' + T_Name + ''' as [Table_Name]'
    + ', Rows_Counted_as_Current = COUNT(status) FROM ' 
    + QUOTENAME(S_Name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(T_Name)
    + 'WHERE status = ''CURRENT'''
FROM table_list
)
SELECT @query = STRING_AGG(MyQueryOnSingleTable, 'UNION ALL ')
FROM MyCTE

PRINT @query
EXECUTE sp_executesql @query
GO
```